# visual effect on constructing nvd3.js pie charts (similar to highcharts)

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I would like to have pie charts created with a nice visual effect similar to highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic/dark-green) when constructing the graphic.

is this possible?

thanks

Comment: Which visual effect are you looking for? There are at least 2 on the chart you linked to.